# How to change the NetBeans IDE language?

Tags: netbeans, language-support

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and NetBeans IDE 7.2.1. My system is set to pt-br, and my NetBeans installation too. I want to use Netbeans in English, how is this possible? I can't find any settings to change the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to change the locale settings when you run Netbeans and see if it uses it.

First you need to generate your locales:

```
sudo locale-gen en_US # or en_GB
sudo locale-gen en_US.utf8
```

Then, from the command line run `LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 netbeans`. If this works you can create a new launcher with that command.

Comment: Would this affect all my other software?

Comment: No. This will only change the locale from the current execution of netbeans. To change it globally you need to use `update-locale`. More info [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale)

Comment: This works perfectly! I had downloaded a non-English languageversion of NetBeans (http://netbeans.org/downloads/), and there's no setting to change the language, but using this I can run it in English! (I just had to type `LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 /path/to/netbeans` instead)

Answer (score 2):

In netbeans 7.3, install from .sh script netbeans.org, in folder of install /usr/local/netbeans-7.3/etc/ change parameters of startup netbeans.conf and add --locale en:US.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the netbeans-7.3.desktop file and add --locale en:US to the Exec parameter, like this:

```
Exec=/bin/sh "/home/duli/netbeans-7.3/bin/netbeans" --locale en:US
```